# Use ActiveModelAdapter to make arbitrary JSON query in ember

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using the standard ActiveModelAdapter in my Ember app to do most of my queries to work with Ember model object.

In one case, however, I want to make a arbitrary REST request to get back JSON to populate a chart (not backed by a model) but I want to go "through" the ActiveModelAdapter so the correct host values are used.

Here's what's not working:

```
updateChartFromIndustry: function() {
  Ember.$.ajax({
    context: this,
    method: 'get',
    url: 'api/v3/charts/all_risk.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { ind: this.get('ind') }
  }).then(function(json) {
      Ember.$('#risk-days-data').highcharts(json);
    },
    function(errs) {
      console.log(errs);
    }
  );
}.observes('ind'),
```

In development, that query goes to localhost:4200 (the ember server) rather than the rails backend at localhost:3000.  Explicitely setting the full URL makes the query go through but without the various user session informatino that authenticates the request.

I'm really hoping for something simple like:

```
this.store.query('arbitrary url and params', ....)
```

as if I were making a normal query for a model or, alternately, to leverage the adapter:

```
Ember.adapter.$.ajax(....)
```

Comment: I think you either have to back the charts with a basic model or include whatever authentication stuff you need in your ajax call.

Comment: In retrospect, I think this is the correct answer. Build a chart model. I may still do that, but current hack is below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting this as "a" way to do this, not necessarily the right way to do it.

The short answer is that the adapter is available (even in components) through the `this.container.lookup('adapter:application')`. It can be used to send AJAX queries directly. I think you can set up your own adapter and override the default behavior but in this case, I was able to trick it into working the way I wanted using the default adapter.

```
updateChartFromIndustry: function() {
  let adapter = this.container.lookup('adapter:application');

  // create the URL. Not that the 'chart' is, by default, pluralized to "charts".
  // This happened to be good for my API.
  // The second parameter becomes the "id" which I use to identify
  // the chart name. 
  // http://localhost:3000/api/v3/charts/all_risk
  let url = adapter.buildURL('chart', 'all_risk'); 

  // object.data is automatically converted into query params
  let params = { data: { ind: this.get('ind') } };

  // make the GET request and build the Chart with the response
  adapter.ajax(url, 'GET', params).then(function(response) {
    Ember.$('#my-chart').highcharts(response);
  });
}.observes('ind'),
```

P.S. this was done with the ActiveModelAdapter but anything that derives from DS.RESTAdapter should allow the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the proxy flag when starting your server:

`ember server   Starts the server. The default port is 4200. Use the --proxy flag to proxy all ajax requests to the given address. For example, ember server --proxy http://127.0.0.1:8080 will proxy all ajax requests to the server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080.`

From http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#using-ember-cli